# How can I remove duplicate words from a string

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to remove duplicate words from the string that I stored in an object like this.

```
const myObj = {
  name: "rishi rishi",
  college: "mnit mnit"
};
```

This is my code to remove duplicate words.

```
const removeDuplicate = (str) => {
  return [...new Set(str.split(" "))].join(" ");
};

for (const key in myObj) {
  removeDuplicate(myObj[key]);
}
```

But this code doesn't remove the duplicate word, it just returns the original string.

Anyone, please help me with this.

Comment: Have you seen <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicate-values-from-js-array>
This link helped me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also have to assign the result of `removeDuplicate` operation otherwise the changes will be discarded. Since you are creating a change but not storing it in any container i.e. `myObj[key]`

```
myObj[key] = removeDuplicate(myObj[key]);
```

```js
const myObj = {
  name: "rishi rishi",
  college: "mnit mnit",
};

const removeDuplicate = (str) => {
  return [...new Set(str.split(" "))].join(" ");
};

for (const key in myObj) {
  myObj[key] = removeDuplicate(myObj[key]);
}

console.log(myObj);
```